# ArchLinux: remove nvidia drivers

Tags: linux, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, amd-catalyst

I recently switched my nVidia card to an ATI one, and am getting a libgl conflict.

When I want to install something related to the GPU, I get the following error:

```
nvidia-utils and catalyst utils are in conflict (libgl). Remove catalyst-utils? (y/n)
```

I don't want to remove the catalyst ones, but the nvidia ones, so I attempted a `pacman -Rs nvidia-utils`. That command says that the target nvidia-utils couldn't be found.

I was using stock (nVidia/ATI) drivers, and tried the official nVidia uninstaller. The uninstaller couldn't find an installation. I cannot remember how I installed the drivers, it's a long time ago ;-).

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you post the output of `pacman -Ss nvidia`?
This command should list the nvidia package installed on your machine. You can then try to remove that package using `pacman -Rcsu <pkg-name>`

Answer (score 3):

Normally the reason you'd get the message is that you're installing nvidia-utils. Are you installing something that depends on nvidia-utils? That could cause it too.

I recommend installing libgl and xf86-video-ati first as a transition step. This should remove your conflicting nvidia drivers. After that's taken care of, install the catalyst package from the AUR. For example:

`pacman -S libgl xf86-video-ati`

`packer -S catalyst`